# Hibernate is saving blank value into the table

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.thejavageek.com/2017/06/16/crud-application-using-angular-4-spring-rest-web-services-spring-data-jpa/) and I'm getting a hang of things. Currently I can make a call from the Angular frontend to save something in the database but the values that are passed into the database are blank:

> Hibernate: select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
>   Hibernate: update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
>   Hibernate: insert into movie (name, id) values (?, ?)

In my `app.component.ts` I have the createMovie() function:

```
createMovie(movie: Movie): void {
  this._dataService.createMovie<Movie>({'id': 20, 'name': 'Star Wars'})
  .subscribe((data) => this.movie = data,
  error => () => {
      'something went wrong';
  },
  () => {
      console.log(this.movies);
  });
}
```

This sends an object with an id and name to the `app.service.ts`.

```
public createMovie<T>(movie: Movie): Observable<T> {
    console.log(movie);
    return this.http.post<T>('/api/movies/', movie);
}
```

This service calls the api end point `/` which is served by the `MovieController.java`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Movie createMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie){
    return movieService.createMovie(movie);
}
```

This call the createMovie function in the `MovieService.java`:

```
Movie createMovie(Movie movie);
```

And this createMovie function is implemented by the `MovieServiceImpl.java`

```
@Override 
public Movie createMovie(Movie movie) {
    return movieRepository.save(movie);
}
```

There is a record created in the movie table in the database but the name value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attached a debugger or added some logging to see if the name is getting populated in the Movie java object?

If it is getting populated, then the error is likely with your ORM mapping. If it isn't getting populated, then the error is likely with the JSON to Object conversion.

Comment: You can. Spring is then deserializes that into your java Movie object.

Comment: What does your Movie class look like? I am assuming just a POJO with getters and settings.